# trimmingCharacters not working as expected when characters include hyphen Swift

Tags: swift

Trying to understand what is going wrong in playgrounds with the next example :

```
let result = "+-----+".trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+").inverted)
```

result is "+-----+"

expected result is "++"

due to method reference "Returns a new string made by removing from both ends of the String characters contained in a given character set."

Examples that work how I expect:

```
let result = "D123ABC".trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "01234567890.").inverted)
```

result is "123"

```
let result = "+-----+".trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "*").inverted)
```

result is ""

Comment: Read the documentation for `trimmingCharacters`. It only removes characters from the ends of the string, not the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`trimmingCharacters` only replaces the trailing/leading characters.

If you want to replace all characters that are not `"+"` you can use

`"+-----+".replacingOccurrences(of: "[^+]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with rmaddy. 
For more explanation check this:

```
let result = "123+--+abc".trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+").inverted)
```

Result: +--+

```
let result = "+--+".trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+").inverted)
```

Result: +--+